# How to sum two column row elements in extra column?

Tags: sqlite, sum, union, window-functions

I'm FULL OUTER JOIN two tables [Givens in db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=86aba8215e5fccb075c3d9b2cd5c2316). The first table name is product_purchase and the second table name is sales_return. They are as follows:

SELECT *FROM 'product_purchase'

| date | invoice_no | product_id | purchase_quantity | price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 10:00:00 | p-101 | A-1 | 100 | 100 |
| 2021-01-02 11:00:00 | p-102 | A-1 | 90 | 90 |
| 2021-01-03 12:00:00 | p-103 | A-1 | 200 | 200 |
| 2021-01-04 13:00:00 | p-104 | A-1 | 250 | 250 |

SELECT *FROM 'sales_return'

| date | invoice_no | product_id | sales_return_quantity | price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 10:00:00 | r-101 | A-1 | 10 | 10 |
| 2021-01-04 13:00:00 | r-104 | A-1 | 25 | 25 |

I wanted to sum product_purchase table column purchase_quantity row elements and sales_return table column sales_return_quantity row elements in extra column total. Following code [Givens in db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=86aba8215e5fccb075c3d9b2cd5c2316), I write to do this.

```
SELECT pp.`date`, pp.`invoice_no`, pp.`product_id`, pp.`purchase_quantity`, sr.`sales_return_quantity`, sum(pp.`purchase_quantity`) OVER (ORDER BY pp.date) AS total
FROM  product_purchase pp
       LEFT JOIN sales_return sr
          ON pp.product_id = sr.product_id AND pp.product_id != sr.product_id
UNION ALL
SELECT sr.`date`, sr.`invoice_no`, sr.`product_id`, pp.`purchase_quantity`, sr.`sales_return_quantity`, sum(sr.`sales_return_quantity`) OVER (ORDER BY sr.date) AS total
FROM   sales_return sr
       LEFT JOIN product_purchase pp
         ON pp.product_id = sr.product_id AND pp.product_id != sr.product_id
WHERE  pp.product_id IS NULL
ORDER BY pp.`date`
```

It sum total column table-wise separately:

| total |
| --- |
| 100 |
| 10 |
| 190 |
| 390 |
| 640 |
| 35 |

It need the following result:

| total |
| --- |
| 100 |
| 110 |
| 200 |
| 400 |
| 650 |
| 675 |

Comment: Are you sure that you want the sales_return_quantity value added to purchase_quantity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of a `FULL` join use `UNION ALL` and `SUM()` window function:

```
SELECT date, invoice_no, product_id, purchase_quantity, sales_return_quantity,
       SUM(COALESCE(purchase_quantity, 0) + COALESCE(sales_return_quantity, 0))
       OVER (ORDER BY date, sales_return_quantity IS NOT NULL) total
FROM (
  SELECT date, invoice_no, product_id, purchase_quantity, null sales_return_quantity
  FROM product_purchase
  UNION ALL
  SELECT date, invoice_no, product_id, null purchase_quantity, sales_return_quantity
  FROM sales_return
)
ORDER BY date, sales_return_quantity IS NOT NULL
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=854de62e36042214a0da83b593a35b05).

Comment: If I add the same date(2021-01-04 13:00:00) on sales_return table column date, it gives the result on total column( 100, 190, 390, 640, 690, 690) here 690 gives two times for the reason of same date. Please suggest to me what's the solution?   [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=a5770b11d94a85faca7d6f8022553d2c)

Comment: @MohammadYasin for this case add DISTINCT: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=ba7fc07bfc5544130372463ecfed403f

Comment: total column need (100, 190, 390, 640, 665, 690)

Comment: @MohammadYasin in this case you need another column to sort the results. Since I don't  see another column for this purpose you can use SQLite's `rowid`: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=02a126dfcfc591963a67bc4003066d6b